# How does flink deal with the opened transaction when failure happens

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.12.0, and I got a question about Flink 2PC mechanism for end-to-end consistency guarantee.

At the start of checkpoint, a transaction is opened, and the transaction is committed after the successful completion of checkpoint.

Then what happens if failure happens? I think the opened transaction should be rolled back? also when the transaction is rolled back? Thanks.

Comment: https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html describes how this works in detail.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the operators and Task Managers are distributed inside a cluster, Flink has to ensure that all components agree together in order to claim that a commit is successful. Flink uses the 2 phase commit protocol, as you said, and with a pre-commit. The pre-commit is the key to deal with failures during the checkpoint, as it says on the [documentation](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html)

> The pre-commit phase finishes when the checkpoint barrier passes through all of the operators and the triggered snapshot callbacks complete.

Comment: Thanks @felipe for he helpful answer and document link!